# Calculating the floor of an element in C++ in O(logn)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

So, I have to calculate the floor of a number in a sorted array in O(logn) where floor means, the greatest number in the array which is smaller than the given number.

```
For example, let the input array be {1, 2, 8, 10, 10, 12, 19}
For x = 0:    floor doesn't exist in array
For x = 1:    floor  = 1
For x = 5:    floor  = 2
For x = 20:   floor  = 19
```

I made the following function:

```
int bina (int arr[], int low, int high, int num)
{
    if ( arr[low] > num )
        return -1;
    else if (arr[high] <= num )
        return high;
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    if ( arr[mid] == num )
        return mid;
    // floor of num lies from low to (mid-1)
    else if (arr[mid] > num)  
    {
        if ( (mid-1) >= low && arr[mid-1] < num )
            return mid-1;
        else
            bina(arr, low, mid-1, num);
    }
    // floor of num lies between (mid+1) to high
    else if ( arr[mid] < num )
    {
        if ( (mid+1) <= high && arr[mid+1] > num )
            return mid;
        else
            bina(arr, low, mid+1, num);
    }
 }
```

This is called in main by the call `bina(arr,0,k-1,n)`. However, on putting these values (in above example), it always returns 1. I don't know what is the problem. I cross-checked my logic 3 times, and it seems to be correct. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: When you call `bina` from that function, what do you want to do with the value returned?  Currently, you're ignoring it.

Comment: Right. I have to return that value too which will yield the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the final case looks suspicious.

Try changing:

```
bina(arr, low, mid+1, num);
```

to

```
return bina(arr, mid+1, high, num);
```

You may also need to add a return to the line `bina(arr, low, mid-1, num);` as well.

Comment: There are *two* suspicious cases.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The code for this task can be simplified by looking at the job a little differently. As it stands, each iteration of your loop basically has a 5-way condition.

When you get down to it, however, there are really only two possible courses of action if we stay in the loop: either we continue searching in the left half of the inputs, or we continue searching in the right half. Likewise, there's really only one condition necessary for exit from the loop: that the left and right sides have narrowed to a single point.

Since I've already written it that way, here's some code in generic form:

```
template <class Iter>
Iter lower_bound(Iter left, 
                 Iter right, 
                 typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type val) 
{
    while (left < right) {
        Iter middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (*middle < val)
            left = middle + 1;
        else
            right = middle;
    }
    return left;
}
```

...and here's a quick bit of test code:

```
#include <iterator>

using std::end;
using std::begin;   

int main() {
    int a[] = {12, 20, 20, 20, 32, 40, 52};
    int targets[] = {10, 19, 20, 22, 40, 60};

    for (auto i : targets) {
        std::cout << "Target: " << i 
                  << ", position: " << lower_bound(begin(a), end(a), i) - a << "\n";

    }
}
```

Also note that with the code written this way, the only change we need to make to get an upper_bound instead of a lower_bound is changing the:

```
    if (*middle < val)
        left = middle + 1;
    else
        right = middle;
```

...to:

```
    if (val < *middle)
        right = middle;
    else
        left = middle + 1;
```

This code works in terms of iterators, so it returns the iterator to the point where you could insert the specified value, and the values would remain ordered, and it would be the first item with that value. If it's smaller than any value in the collection, it'll return the iterator to the first item. If it's larger than any item in the collection, it'll return collection.end() (which is just past the last item).